# Google Fusion Tables SQL Query ORDER BY and GROUP BY in same query doesn't work

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, google-fusion-tables

I'm writing a mobile web page using Google Fusion Tables for my data and I need to use both `ORDER BY` (lat and long) as well as `GROUP BY` (in place of `DISTINCT` - which GFT doesn't support).

But, it seems the two do not play well together.  If I use `GROUP BY`, the statement seems to simply ignore the `ORDER BY`.

SQL statement:

```
SELECT Count(), Facility_Name FROM 2206340 GROUP BY Facility_Name 
ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(Lat, LATLNG(" + lat + "," + lng + "))LIMIT 10
```

Has anyone else run into this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can't order by a column that isn't included in the select/group by clause (unless you use an aggregate function)

Comment: So you're using ST_DISTANCE() to find the distance from your predefined point to the facility which can calculate different distances for each row (If you have 2 facilities with the same name).

If you did something like MAX(ST_DISTANCE(Lat, LATLNG(" + lat + "," + lng + "))) it would work (provided you want to order by the maximum distance)

Comment: You could also add ST_DISTANCE(Lat, LATLNG(" + lat + "," + lng + ")) to your select and group by clause and you would get the results you're after.

Comment: I'm getting what you're saying, but Google doesn't like ORDER BY MAX(ST_DISTANCE(Lat, LATLNG(" + lat + "," + lng + ")))

Comment: Google also doesn't like ST_DISTANCE(Lat, LATLNG(" + lat + "," + lng + ")) in the select portion.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. Just tried it myself and I'm surprised the order by even runs & returns results. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Well, you're not alone.  No one in the GFT group seems to know what's going on either.  :-/  Might have to scrap this plan and go back to MySQL.  I appreciate the input anyway! :-)

Comment: The frustrating thing is that I can use the aggregation and sorting in the GFT table itself so some SQL must exist that makes it possible. It would be nice to be able to create a view from the applied aggregation!